# add entires from textfield to UITableView to automatically populate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

This is the code I have so far. I am able to enter into the textfield and have it appear in the UITableView, but only after I reload the page and come back to it. I want for what I enter into the textfield and when I click 'add' for it to automatically appear in the UITableView.

```
@IBOutlet var itemTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

var items: [String] = []

@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

    var items:[String]

    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {
        items = tempItems
        items.append(itemTextField.text!)

        print(items)
    } else {
        items = [itemTextField.text!]
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items" )
    itemTextField.text = ""
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Type02", size: 20)

    return cell
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let itemsOBject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

    if let tempItems = itemsOBject as? [String]{
        items = tempItems
    }

    table.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        table.reloadData()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    }
}
```

Comment: Reload table on add function then just after you append data in array , instead doing in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I tried this solution but no luck... I have to go back a ViewController and come back to the ViewController with the textfield and TableView and only then will it appear... Any other ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me .

Add outlet for `textfield` and `tableview`.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var nametextField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!
```

Add `IBAction` for **Add** action `button`.

```
@IBAction func addNameToTable(_ sender: Any) {

        // Check for value in nameTextField
        guard let profilename = nametextField.text else{
          return
        }
        // Append text field value in data array
        data.append(profilename)
       // Reload table to show text field name in table
        dataTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Create `array` to hold string values-:

```
var data = [String]()
```

Add `table` methods to populate data on table on clicking Add button.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented

    // return array count
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }

    // dequeue cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // Row height
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 50
    }
```

**COMPLETE CODE -:**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nametextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!
    var data = [String]()

    //MArk-: ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addNameToTable(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let profilename = nametextField.text else{
          return
        }
        data.append(profilename)
        dataTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") 
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 50
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the table view to `reloadData()` whenever the items array changes. So try adding `table.reloadData()` to the end of your `add` function.

Comment: I tried this solution but no luck... I have to go back a ViewController and come back to the ViewController with the textfield and TableView and only then will it appear... Any other ideas...