# Use UITextField to add row at end of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have a UITableView with 2 sections, in the first one there is the cells that each represent the different item from an array, and the second one calls a UIAlertController with a textfield.  I want whatever I write in the textfield to show in the first section of the tableView.  My code currently is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedCaseSolutionsForCell[indexPath.row], forKey: "ollShowAlg\(selectedCaseID)")
        print("OLL Case with ID \(selectedCaseID) had its main algorithm changed to \(selectedCaseSolutionsForCell[indexPath.row])")
        let newMainSolve : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ollShowAlg\(selectedCaseID)")!
        print("THE ALGORITHM IS NOW \(newMainSolve)")


    case 1:
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Algoritm", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField()
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
            let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
            print("Text field: \(textField!.text!)")

        }))
        present(alert, animated: true)

    default:
        return
    }      
}
```

How can I add the textfield input to the array and then show that at the end of the UITableView?  This question is not a duplicate as I'm not using a custom cell and don't have an IBOutlet or IBAction for it.

Comment: See this Post to achieve your goal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906626/add-entires-from-textfield-to-uitableview-to-automatically-populate

Comment: where is your array show it and what it contains ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the table's data source is an array of string named `data`. Something like this:

```
fileprivate var data: [String] = []
```

Then all you have to do after this line `print("Text field: \(textField!.text!)")` is add the following:

```
self.table.beginUpdates()
self.data.append(textField!.text!)
self.table.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: self.data.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
self.table.endUpdates()
```